# JLabel positioned on top of TextPane, disappears when text pane repainting

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have positioned a Jlabel on top of a text pane, which acts like a top border to the textpane. My problem is when typing on the textpane, the label get disappeared. Please give me a way to keep the jlabel visible all the time.

Thanks in advance.

---------Edit---------

Giving a code sample would be lengthy. Please refer the images below to get an idea about what happens.

1)  before typing in textPane.
[image: Before typing in text pane]

2) after typing.
[image]

Comment: Please give us some example code.  Also, why not use a `TitledBorder`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  An SSCCE, by definition, is not 'lengthy'.